pptpclient rejects CHAP MD5 auth
I am using an Arch Linux router to connect to ISP's VPN, and for some reason CHAP auth is rejected:
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MD5> <mru 1436> <magic 0x5e9f9414>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth chap MD5>]

How can this be fixed?
Full info
Logs
root@Chiruno:~# pon wan debug dump logfd 2 nodetach
pppd options in effect:
debug           # (from command line)
nodetach                # (from command line)
logfd 2         # (from command line)
ifname wan              # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
dump            # (from command line)
noauth          # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-pap              # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
                # (from /etc/ppp/options)
                # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-mschap-v2                # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
refuse-eap              # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
name username           # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
remotename PPTP         # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
                # (from /etc/ppp/options.pptp)
pty /usr/sbin/pptp pptp.isp --nolaunchpppd          # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
ipparam $TUNNEL         # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
defaultroute            # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
replacedefaultroute             # (from /etc/ppp/peers/wan)
nobsdcomp               # (from /etc/ppp/options)
nodeflate               # (from /etc/ppp/options)
using channel 672
Using interface wan
Connect: wan <--> /dev/pts/6
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x6fec8267> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MD5> <mru 1436> <magic 0x5e9f9414>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <magic 0x6fec8267>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <auth chap MD5> <mru 1436> <magic 0x5e9f9414>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x2 <auth chap MD5>]
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
Script /usr/sbin/pptp pptp.isp --nolaunchpppd finished (pid 40392), status = 0x0

Configuration
/etc/ppp/options.pptp
###############################################################################
# $Id: options.pptp,v 1.4 2012/08/30 21:34:13 quozl Exp $
#
# Sample PPTP PPP options file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
# Options used by PPP when a connection is made by a PPTP client.
# This file can be referred to by an /etc/ppp/peers file for the tunnel.
# Changes are effective on the next connection.  See "man pppd".
#
# You are expected to change this file to suit your system.  As
# packaged, it requires PPP 2.4.2 or later from http://ppp.samba.org/
# and the kernel MPPE module available from the CVS repository also on
# http://ppp.samba.org/, which is packaged for DKMS as kernel_ppp_mppe.
###############################################################################

# Lock the port
lock

# Authentication
# We don't need the tunnel server to authenticate itself
noauth

# We won't do PAP, EAP, MSCHAP or MSCHAP-V2 but we will accept CHAP
# (you may need to remove these refusals if the server is not using MPPE)
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-mschap
refuse-mschap-v2

remotename PPTP

# Compression
# Turn off compression protocols we know won't be used
#nobsdcomp
#nodeflate

# Encryption
# (There have been multiple versions of PPP with encryption support,
# choose which of the following sections you will use.  Note that MPPE
# requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
#
# Note that using PPTP with MPPE and MSCHAP-V2 should be considered
# insecure:
# http://marc.info/?l=pptpclient-devel&m=134372640219039&w=2
# https://github.com/moxie0/chapcrack/blob/master/README.md
# http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2743314

# http://ppp.samba.org/ the PPP project version of PPP by Paul Mackarras
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# If the kernel is booted in FIPS mode (fips=1), the ppp_mppe.ko module
# is not allowed and PPTP-MPPE is not available.
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#require-mppe-128
# }}}

# http://mppe-mppc.alphacron.de/ fork from PPP project by Jan Dubiec
# ppp-2.4.2 or later with MPPE and MPPC, kernel module ppp_mppe_mppc.o
# {{{
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
#mppe required,stateless
# }}}

/etc/ppp/peers/wan
pty "/usr/sbin/pptp pptp.isp --nolaunchpppd"
name username
remotename PPTP
require-chap
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ifname wan
ipparam $TUNNEL
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute

/etc/ppp/chap-secrets
# user          remote  secret          IP addresses
"username"      PPTP    "P4ssw0rd!1!"   *


Turns out I forgot that /etc/ppp/options (which in my case contained a pesky little refuse-chap) was still checked. Do not repeat my mistakes!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
